# Cancelling a Task started by ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, signalr

#### Background

The following server side code is used to spin up a long-running task that will post updates to the web front end via SignalR. I've placed a button on the front end that I then want to stop the task at the user's request.

#### Issue

When front end trigger's the `Stop` method, the `tokenSource` is null. I suspect, this is because it's not reaching the same instance of the `ChartHub` that spawned the Task.

#### Code

```
using System;
...
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace dvvWeb.Hubs
{
public class ChartHub : Hub
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    CancellationToken ct;
    public void Start(string serverName, string dbName, string numberOfPoints, string pollingFrequency)
    {
        ConfigModel config = new ConfigModel();

        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ct = tokenSource.Token;

        config.Servername = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(serverName);
        config.DbName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(dbName);
        config.Preferences.NumberOfPoints = int.Parse(numberOfPoints);
        config.Preferences.PollingFrequency = int.Parse(pollingFrequency);

        dvvGraphingModel graphingModel = new dvvGraphingModel();

        dvvGraphingHelper graphingHelper = new dvvGraphingHelper(graphingModel, config.Servername, config.DbName);

        graphingModel = graphingHelper.Tick(config.Preferences);

        var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        Task.Run(() => workItemAsync(ct, graphingModel, graphingHelper, config, identity));
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }


    private async Task<CancellationToken> workItemAsync(CancellationToken ct, dvvGraphingModel graphingModel, dvvGraphingHelper graphingHelper, ConfigModel configModel, WindowsIdentity identity)
    {
        await addDataAsync(ct, graphingModel, graphingHelper, configModel, identity);
        return ct;
    }

    private async Task<CancellationToken> addDataAsync(CancellationToken ct, dvvGraphingModel graphingModel, dvvGraphingHelper graphingHelper, ConfigModel configModel, WindowsIdentity identity)
    {

        try
        {
            while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                identity.Impersonate();
                Clients.Caller.addPointToChart(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(graphingModel));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(configModel.Preferences.PollingFrequency * 1000);
                graphingModel = graphingHelper.Tick(configModel.Preferences);

            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Caught TaskCanceledException - signaled cancellation " + tce.Message);
        }
        return ct;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: SignalR hub instances are created at every user request, so you cannot have that cancellation token there.
Why don't you use a Singleton?

Comment: Wouldn't the singleton be scoped to the entire worker process? If multiple users are using the application, only that user's `Task` should be stopped.

Comment: Why do you use `Task.Run(() => workItemAsync(ct, graphingModel, graphingHelper, config, identity));` rather than making `Start()` async?

Comment: This might be the one of the few times that I would suggest maintaining a (thread-safetied) static list of cancellation tokens. Otherwise, I sense a lot of pain waiting to happen...

Comment: @xleon `Start()` is being called indirectly through the SignalR hub from the front end, I haven't tried making it directly `async`.

Comment: Yeah, try it. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>` where 'string' would be the user name/id or maybe

`ConcurrentDictionary<IUserIdentity, CancellationTokenSource>`.

Well, that´s in the case a user can only start one process at a time.

That dictionary would live in a Singleton class outside of the Hub. Your hub would be just a proxy to call methods in your singleton.

```
YourSingleton.Instance.Start(userId, serverName, dbName, numberOfPoints, pollingFrequency);
```

and

```
YourSingleton.Instance.Stop(userId);
```

Then, you could do something like:

```
public void Stop(string userId)
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    if(dictionary.TryGetValue(userId, out tokenSource))
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        dictionary.TryRemove(userId out tokenSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to dispose the token source?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but I didn´t try it so I don´t know about any side effects.